# Add html table dynamically on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding data to the database on a button click event. I am trying to display the added data to the database, in the form of html table on the same page in the same button click event. But I am unable to view the table on the page. I tried debugging but everything looks to be fine.

Here is the small piece of code.

```
void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Objects.InsertNewRequestIntoMaterialTransactions(...);
            LoadMaterialTakenTable();

        }
 void LoadMaterialTakenTable()
        {
            Table tblMaterialList = new Table();

            placeMaterialRequest.Controls.Add(tblMaterialList);
        }
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading a blank table.  Once you create your new table tblMaterialList, you have to then populate the table before you add it to your placeMaterialRequest control.

You can find out exactly how to build a table from microsoft here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753342.aspx

Comment: I did not place the entire code that comes inside the table. However, I am adding the rows and cells to the table. But the thing is I am unable to view this table.

Comment: I guess we would have to see the html code where placeMaterialRequest exists.